# A question about if you can say that a summation of a function diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Suppose that we had a function $f(x)\subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and $x\in \Bbb{N}$, and suppose that:
$$\sum_{x\geq 1} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$$
My question is, if this summation diverges, even though $\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|<\left|f(x)\right|$, then, can we say the following as well?
$$\sum_{x\geq 1} f(x)=\infty$$

Comment: This is not clear.  Uncountable sums of positive terms all diverge...at least under pretty much any sensible definition of the sum.  What do you mean by the sum?

Comment: @lulu I think the question is asking about the real sequence $a_n$ and in particular whether$$\sum\frac{a_n}n=\infty\implies\sum a_n=\infty$$

Comment: @PeterForeman That is what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, I don't think this is true.
Let's define:
$$a_{2n}=2n,a_{2n+1}=-2n$$
we know that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{2n}\dfrac{a_{n}}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{a_{2i}}{2i}+\dfrac{a_{2i+1}}{2i+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{2i}{2i+1}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{2i+1}\right)\to\infty$$
on the other hand it is easy to see that the sum of a_n doesn't direverge to infinity.